# Is there a way to rotate an Ellipse in libGDX for collision detection purposes?

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, rotation

I'm trying to avoid having multiple overlapping Circles for a UFO-shaped sprite.

Two Ellipse objects will perfectly cover the shape of my UFO, but I want to tilt/rotate the UFO when flying left and right, while still maintaining collision areas that match the locations of the graphics.

The Ellipse reference page doesn't have anything listed for rotation options, just wondering if anyone has ever tried to do this before (and succeeded).